# How to get gmail emails in my website

Tags: json, email, gmail

Is there a way to get emails from gmail using some API for emails to go directly in front end of web application through some JSON api or XML format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get gmail emails using GMAIL API's ... XOAUTH will come into picture in it.

Step 1.  Use OAUTH 2.0 to get access token and refresh token of GMAIL account.

Step 2.  Use that access Token in XOAUTH and with the help of GMAIL API's access all the folders and emails from GMAIL.

Please refer -> https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview for more information

There are no libraries available for front end .. ie JSON or XML..
You have to use either python ,java or PHP..

You can refere: http://context.io/ ... which might help you for what u need...

http://context.io/  provides API's through which you can access and sync your email through REST .
You would get response in form of JSON which you can easily parse... Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks bro. Can context.io get gmail emails for me?

Comment: https://github.com/contextio/AppEngineDemo

Please Refer this... They have also provided demo app URL ... which is really good..

Comment: http://googleappengine.blogspot.in/2011/05/accessing-gmail-accounts-from-app.html

Comment: I think context.io are converting emails by accessing in IMAP and providing access layer in REST. What you say?

Comment: Yes it does that...what it is a great API ... and very easy to implement..rather than creating your own functions from scratch